# Why does my Perl CGI script raise an internal server error on Apache?

Tags: apache2, perl, webapp-development

I've installed `apache2` on Ubuntu 11.04, and [localhost](http://127.0.0.1) is working. I created a simple printenv.pl script and put it in the following directory

```
$ mv printenv.pl /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
$ chmod +rx /usr/lib/cgi-bin/printenv.pl
```

However when I go to http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/printenv.pl, I get a 500 Internal Server Error

I checked the error log at `/var/log/apache2`, and this is what it says:

```
[Mon Oct 24 11:04:25 2011] [error] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/printenv.pl' failed
[Mon Oct 24 11:04:25 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: printenv.pl
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this and run CGI scripts on my localhost?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well.  It turned out that I had set the `.pl` files permissions to `775`.  Apache does not allow user writable.  Try changing your `.pl` file permissions to `755`.

If that isn't it, check your web site permission settings in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem (with the exact same paths, directories, permissions, etc.) just a little while ago, and all of a sudden understood what I read somewhere in the Apach2 documentation about a week ago.

That is this - everything you have set up so far is fine, but for security reasons, apache will **not** run any file (CGI, Perl, C, etc.) unless its **write permission (w) is removed completely**.

Make the permissions look like this: `-r-xr-xr-x`

Then it should work just fine.  Hope this helps, let me know if it still doesn't work.